# The report can not be loaded for SAP Crystal Server 2013 Evaluation

Tags: crystal-reports

All , I was following the guide from [Here](http://global12.sap.com/campaign/ne/free_trial/crystal_reports_server_2013/wty_int_crystal_reports_server_2013.epx?Level=1&FormResultID=60f087d7-4ab0-4efd-a30f-05933dac83ac&ContinueURL=%2fcampaign%2fne%2ffree_trial%2fcrystal_reports_server_2013%2findex.ep) and tring to integrate the `SAP Crystal Reports for Enterprise` and `SAP Crystal Server 2013 SP1 Client Tools` to work together. all of them are installed without problem. But every reports I build from `Sap Crystal Reports for Enterprise` can not be loaded in my test vs2010 web project .

So I wondered if these two can work together well. because my test code is very simple. But unfortunatedly it failed. I have been working on it for couple of days. But does't get it work.  the code and exception shows below .Please help to review it .

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/test123.rpt")); // This line failed.
        System.Console.Write("ok!!!");

    }
```

the exception says :

```
Load report failed.

    Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack.

    Source: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()

       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)

       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)

       at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\Study\VS2010\WebSite3\Default.aspx.cs:line 16

       at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)

       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)

       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)

       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()

       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Did I miss something or do something wrong ? If there is please kindly tell me . thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try installing the Crystal Reports for Visual Studio runtime and try it then. Download can be found here: http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_7.exe

Comment: As I known so far , The report generated by CR for Enterprise can't be populated by regular way like using CR sdk for .net, The recommended way is using RESTful API or URL open. If your met the same problem like above, I hope this comment is helpful to you . thanks.